# How to present an expression in the form: $f(h)= c +O(h^\alpha) = c +o(h^{\beta})$?

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

We have functions: $e^h,(1-h^{4})^{-1}, \cos(h), 1 +\sin(h^3)$.
These functions have the same limit. How to present an expression in the form: $f(h)= c +O(h^\alpha) = c +o(h^{\beta})$, where $h \to 0$, choosing the best integer number $\alpha, \beta$.

I have that $$f(h) = e^h, $$ $$\lim_{h\to 0} e^h =1$$ then $e^h =\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{h^k}{k!} $ but I don't know, what I should do...

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Look at the Taylor series of the functions.

Comment: @Gary could you help me? How I should prove it? Because I don't know. I have $e^h = 1 + h + \frac{h^2}{2}+ ...$ and I obtain $e^h - 1 =  h + \frac{h^2}{2}+ ... $.